# Copy directory tree with empty files

Tags: macos, bash

I am looking to create a copy of a folder tree with empty files in it. The files in the source folders are not empty but I want the files in the destination folders to be empty. (I don’t think I can just use soft/hard link because **I am on Mac OS X**, right?) It’s to keep track of the content of many external hard drives with a lot of larges video files in them.

I found `rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" source/ destination/` to copy the folders but I didn't find a way to create the empty files (I tried a tcsh `foreach` but it failed because there are spaces in folders name).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the purpose of this?  Seems like an achievable problem, but it's odd enough that it sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you *really* trying to do?  If you want to keep track of what files are on what external drives, why not simply keep text files with the output of `find` on each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the answer from ursusd8, here's a recursive solution that will work in bash version 4, if you have that installed...

```
shopt -s globstar
cd /path/to/source/
for f in **/*; do
  mkdir -p "/path/to/target/${f%/*}"   # make the containing directory if required
  touch "/path/to/target/$f"           # make a zero-length file
done
```

This runs the `mkdir` command many more times than required, but it's quick.  Note that bash 4 may not be available on your system unless you've explicitly installed it using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/.) or the like.

A longer alternative would be to separate the steps of creating your directory tree and touching the files:

```
cd /path/to/source/
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /path/to/target/{} \;
find . -type f -exec touch /path/to/target/{} \;
```

Note that this two-stage `find` solution uses no bashisms, and can likely be run in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which can even handle uncommon filenames correctly (like filenames with a newline inside etc.)

It will first create the directory tree and then create empty files. additional external commands other than `find`, `mkdir` and `touch` are required.

```
#!/bin/bash

# IMPORTANT: SOURCE and DESTINATION have to be absolute pathes
# To fix the missing parameter -printf of find in mac os x,
# i used a technique to reproduce the functionality.
# But now it IS IMPORTANT that both of these variables contain an absolute path!

SOURCE="/home/you/source_dir/"
DESTINATION="/where/ever/destination_dir/"

#first 'copy' the directory tree
while
    IFS="" read -r -d '' -u 9 dir
do
    #remove the $SOURCE part
    dir="${dir#${SOURCE}}"

    mkdir "${DESTINATION}/${dir}"
done 9< <(find "${SOURCE}" -type d -print0)

#then create empty files inside the new tree
while
    IFS="" read -r -d '' -u 9 file
do
    #remove the $SOURCE part
    file="${file#${SOURCE}}"

    touch "${DESTINATION}/${file}"
done 9< <(find "${SOURCE}" -type f -print0)
```

**EDIT:**
Removed usage of `-printf` of `find` tool, as it seemingly didn't exists in mac os x - used bash parameter substitution to recreate the behavior.

Comment: Thanks! But, find -printf doesn't seems to exist in Mac OS X

Comment: @ElieV I can rewrite this script so it will work for you. I just need to know if i can rely on a proper `bash` or do you need to have it done in `tcsh`?

Comment: Thanks again! On OS X, I have bash version 3.2.57 (the OS X Yosemite stock version) and tcsh v6.17.00 (the OS X Yosemite stock version)

Comment: @ElieV I have edited the script so it recreates the -printf behavior. Save it as is to e.g. `tree.sh` and it should work with your bash version. Be careful to use absolute pathnames! - As the way I used to recreate the `-printf` behavor just strips the `$SOURCE` part from `file` and adds the remaining string to `$DESTINATION/`. So if you use relative pathnames here, it will not work at all. You could possibly work around that by setting `SOURCE=$(readlink -f ../rela/path)` and the same for `DESTINATION` so the script will work with absolute pathnames internally (Just in case you need that).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `touch` in for loop:

```
cd /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/
for f in *; 
 do touch /PATH/TO/DEST/FOLDER/$f; 
done
```

EDIT:
The code above will give you all files and folders in `/SOURCE/FOLDER`, but will **not be recursive**. 
To create empty files only for source files and to create a directory tree(all the subfolders), you can use:

```
FILES=$(find /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/ -type f) 
for f in $FILES; 
do touch /PATH/TO/DEST/FOLDER/$f;
done
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried but can I do this recursively (create empty files for all files in subfolders?

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4 or later, use `shopt -s globstar; for f in **/*; do`

Comment: You can try something like this :

`FILES=$(find /PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/ -type f)
for f in $FILES; 
 do touch /PATH/TO/DEST/FOLDER/$f; 
done`

This should create a tree of empty files.